# getting error "TypeError: events.listenForEvents is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack

I have this code below and im getting the error "TypeError: events.listenForEvents is not a function". what could be the wrong of my script? thank you!

````
const { App, LogLevel } = require('@slack/bolt')
const clientOptions = {
  // enable this for dev instance
  // slackApiUrl: 'https://dev.slack.com/api/'
}

const port = process.env.PORT
// Log level is one of the options you can set in the constructor
const app = new App({
  socketMode: true,
  appToken: process.env.SLACK_APP_TOKEN,
  clientOptions,
  token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN
  // logLevel: LogLevel.DEBUG
})

const events = require('./events')
const interactions = require('./interactions')
 
events.listenForEvents(app)
interactions.listenForInteractions(app)

app.start(function () {
  console.log(`Bot started`)
})```
````

Comment: This means that whatever is inside `./events` doesn't export an object with a `listenForEvents` function

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: Make whatever is being exported from `./events` export an object with the correct functionality / methods. It looks like you're expecting it to be an object with a `listenForEvents`, but it doesn't have this method. You need to update your code in the events file so it includes the method you want to use

Comment: @NickParsons here is my events.js file. function listenForEvents(app) {app.message('hello', async ({ message, say }) => {await say(`Hey there<@${message.user}>!`);});}

Comment: What are you exporting from the file? If it's just the function then you can do `const listenForEvents = require('./events');` and then use it like so `listenForEvents(app);`

Comment: now im getting TypeError: listenForEvents is not a function

Comment: Then you're not exporting a function? Are you doing `module.exports` in your events file? Please share full code and add it to your question rather than a comment so that it is correctly formatted and readable

Comment: @NickParsons just added this line module.exports.listenForEvents = listenForEvents in events.js file and it works. thank so much!